# How should I install homebrew into /usr/local subdirectory manually?

Tags: macos, command-line, installation, shell, homebrew

[Manual installation directions in docs.brew.sh](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) are very brief and unsatisfactory, resulting in some errors if I try it in a subdirectory of `/usr/local` without using `sudo`. Directions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725813/how-to-install-homebrew-manually) along with its [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725987/1283667) are a little better but also do not work without using `sudo`.

I understand that I may need to use `sudo` to install Homebrew itself but hope I do not need to continue using `sudo` to install new packages, update, etc. (Standard Homebrew install scripts seem to use `sudo` but only when absolutely necessary, while the standard result is that there is no need to use `sudo` to install new packages, update, etc.)

How should I manually install Homebrew into a `/usr/local` subdirectory?

Motivation for manual installation info `/usr/local` subdirectory:

- Manual installation gives me the best control over the process of installation and management of Homebrew.
- Installation into subdirectory of my home directory is not ideal since Homebrew manages a combination of locally built packages and system-wide packages.

Motivation for avoiding the need for the user to use `sudo` after installation:

- consistency with standard installation
- easier to manage existing Homebrew packages
- lower security risk if Homebrew itself or Homebrew packages do not compel the user to run some things as root

Comment: Why is using sudo a problem (might be worth mentioning in the question)?

Comment: @fixer1234 it is clarified in the question.

Comment: The standard installation of homebrew avoids having to use sudo after installation, and while it's true you don't have control over what's going on with the "official" method, all it does is create subdirectories in `/usr/local` with the user as the owner (to avoid sudo later). So I don't really understand the motivation to do that manually, having to get all the details right yourself.

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: This answer assumes that the macOS user is setup as an administrator. Please see **IMPORTANT** note:

**IMPORTANT:** do not use `sudo` unless absolutely necessary as described below. The end result should be a Homebrew installation that does not need the use of `sudo` ever again.

Recommended method as of June 2021:

Use `sudo` to make a subdirectory such as `opt` that Homebrew can be installed under, and use your own login password if needed:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/opt
```

and sudo `sudo` **only** once more to take ownership of the subdirectory under the `staff` group, for example:

```
sudo chown brodybits:staff /usr/local/opt
```

At this point `sudo` should no longer be needed for installing or using Homebrew.

`ls -al /usr/local` should now show the new subdirectory, for example:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 root       wheel  160 May 13 17:13 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root       wheel  352 Jan  1  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root       wheel    0 Oct 16  2018 .com.apple.installer.keep
drwxr-xr-x   4 root       wheel  128 May 13 17:13 bak
drwxr-xr-x   2 brodybits  staff   64 May 13 17:03 opt
```

Now use Git to clone [`Homebrew/brew` from GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew) into the new subdirectory, for example:

```
cd /usr/local/opt
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
ls -al /usr/local/opt # recommended
```

Optional: It is possible to rename the newly installed `brew` subdirectory, if so desired. It is also optional to move the new `brew` subdirectory up to the `/usr/local` level (`sudo` may be needed just once more for this).

Update the desired profile file (`$HOME/.zprofile` or `$HOME/.zshenv` in case of zsh, for example) to add the new Homebrew `bin` subdirectory to the `PATH` environment variable. Here is an example:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/brew/bin:$PATH
```

(See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725987/1283667).)

Restart the shell, start a new shell, or source the profile file. It is recommended to check that `which brew` shows it in the right place,  `/usr/local/opt/brew/bin/brew`.

At this point, `brew --version` should show some information (with no `homebrew-core` installed at this point), for example:

```
Homebrew 3.1.7-36-g7c68b17
Homebrew/homebrew-core N/A
```

Then run `brew update` to include `homebrew-core` and run `brew doctor` to verify proper installation. It will likely output some warning messages about the non-standard Homebrew prefix but this should be an issue for most packages.

`brew --version` after `brew doctor` should show `homebrew-core` included, for example:

```
Homebrew 3.1.7-36-g7c68b17
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 61cc59c956; last commit 2021-05-13)
```

Try installing a simple formula such as `autoconf`:

```
brew install autoconf
```

`autoconf --version` should now show that it is installed.

See further below for some optional followup steps.

---

Outdated solution from 2018 **no longer tested or updated**:

First make a temporary directory within `/usr/local` using `sudo` (enter password if requested):

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/brewtmp1
```

Check the results of `ls -l /usr/local`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root       wheel   64 Jul  2 16:16 brewtmp1
```

Fix the user and group ownership of the temporary directory:

```
sudo chown $USER:admin brewtmp1
```

Check the results of `ls -l /usr/local` again:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 brodybits  admin   64 Jul  2 16:16 brewtmp1
```

Then within the temporary directory download and extract the contents of `master` branch of [Homebrew/brew on GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew) **without using `sudo`**:

```
cd /usr/local/brewtmp1
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz
```

Check the results of `ls -l` within `/usr/local/brewtmp1`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  16 brodybits  admin  512 Jul  2 14:46 Homebrew-brew-cbc3184
```

Check the results of `ls -l Homebrew-brew-*`:

```
total 48
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin    98 Jul  2 14:46 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin  3161 Jul  2 14:46 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin   720 Jul  2 14:46 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin  1334 Jul  2 14:46 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x   7 brodybits  admin   224 Jul  2 14:46 Library
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin  7374 Jul  2 14:46 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 brodybits  admin    96 Jul  2 14:46 bin
drwxr-xr-x   5 brodybits  admin   160 Jul  2 14:46 completions
drwxr-xr-x  48 brodybits  admin  1536 Jul  2 14:46 docs
drwxr-xr-x   5 brodybits  admin   160 Jul  2 14:46 manpages
```

This should show the contents of Homebrew with correct user and group.

Rename `Homebrew-brew-???????` to `homebrew` **(without using `sudo`)** (it should be OK to use another name, with adaptations to other steps below):

```
mv Homebrew-brew-??????? homebrew
```

and double-check the results of `ls -l`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  16 brodybits  admin  512 Jul  2 14:46 homebrew
```

Move the new `homebrew` directory to the right place using `sudo`:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/brewtmp1/homebrew /usr/local
```

Double-check the results of `ls -l /usr/local`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 brodybits  admin   64 Jul  2 16:20 brewtmp1
drwxr-xr-x  16 brodybits  admin  512 Jul  2 14:46 homebrew
```

Add the following line to profile file (`.profile` or `.bash_profile` as appropriate) (as directed by [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725987/1283667)):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Restart shell, start new shell, or source the profile file. Check that `which brew` shows `/usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew`. Check that `brew --version` works (though with no `homebrew-core` installed) for example:

```
Homebrew >=1.4.0 (shallow or no git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-core N/A
```

It is recommended to do `brew doctor` at this point, which will include `homebrew-core` and verify proper installation. It may output a warning about non-standard Homebrew prefix but this should be an issue for most packages. Then `brew --version` should show `homebrew-core` included:

```
Homebrew >=1.4.0 (shallow or no git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 2f937; last commit 2018-07-02)
```

Try installing a simple formula such as `autoconf`:

```
brew install autoconf
```

`autoconf --version` should now show that it is installed.

`ls -l /usr/local/homebrew` should now look like this:

```
total 48
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin    98 Jul  2 16:43 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin  3161 Jul  2 16:43 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin   720 Jul  2 16:43 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 brodybits  admin    96 Jul  2 16:43 Cellar
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin  1334 Jul  2 16:43 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x   8 brodybits  admin   256 Jul  2 16:43 Library
-rw-r--r--   1 brodybits  admin  7374 Jul  2 16:43 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  10 brodybits  admin   320 Jul  2 16:43 bin
drwxr-xr-x   5 brodybits  admin   160 Jul  2 16:43 completions
drwxr-xr-x  48 brodybits  admin  1536 Jul  2 16:43 docs
drwxr-xr-x   3 brodybits  admin    96 Jul  2 16:43 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 brodybits  admin   160 Jul  2 16:43 manpages
drwxr-xr-x   4 brodybits  admin   128 Jul  2 16:43 opt
drwxr-xr-x   8 brodybits  admin   256 Jul  2 16:43 share
drwxr-xr-x   3 brodybits  admin    96 Jul  2 16:42 var
```

It is now recommended to add some possibly missing directories and fix some directory permissions to match the results of the Homebrew install script (I wish `brew doctor` would check and offer to take care of this part):

```
cd /usr/local/homebrew
mkdir -p include Caskroom Cellar lib opt share var
chmod g+w include Caskroom Cellar lib opt share var
```

And finally cleanup `/usr/local/brewtmp1` (using `sudo`):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/brewtmp1
```

---

**Optional followup steps:**

To disable analytics (thanks to [this article](https://osxdaily.com/2018/03/07/how-install-homebrew-mac-os/), must be done after installing a package):

```
brew analytics off
```

You can [`Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions) to get access to alternate versions such as daily and beta versions, as they have documented:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
```

---

Additional reading and other resources from 2018:

- [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725987/1283667)
- [How to install Homebrew by OSX Daily](https://osxdaily.com/2018/03/07/how-install-homebrew-mac-os/) (using standard script)
- [9 of the best Homebrew packages for mac by OSX Daily](https://osxdaily.com/2018/03/26/best-homebrew-packages-mac/)